# In Sitecore helix how to reuse feature-project views in project-layer

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, rendering, helix, sitecore-habitat

I am new to helix pattern in sitecore. Please find below points

1. I have Main website project in Project//CDB.Helix.Sitecore.Project.website
   like below solution structure

   [image]
2. In website project i have PageLayout view that refrencing a placeholder for 
   Feature //CDB.Helix.Sitecore.Feature.Header's controller rendering.

   [image]
3. When i add reference CDB.Helix.Sitecore.Feature.Header in main project 
   CDB.Helix.Sitecore.Project.website
4. Views/BasicHeader is not identified by main project.
5. How do i reuse the HeaderProject views in my main project,
   How to reference effectively?

Comment: Changed tag 'habitat' to 'sitecore-habitat'. Part of effort to split up ambiguous tag 'habitat'

Answer (score 3):

1) It is important to understand how the references should be in helix with the tree layers, so it should be one way with the following order :
 project-> feature -> Foundation:
[image]

and as I see what you have done is right.

2) Then you should have placeholder lets call it "**phBasicHeader**" in your page layout, and this is a placholder key, where the header should be rendered:

```
@Html.Sitecore.Placeholder("phBasicHeader")
```

3) Now from Sitecore you should have rendering (controller or view) for your basicview.chtml :

[image]

4) Then from Sitecore, you add this view rendering to your item or template standard values, on the **phBasicHeader**  like this:

[image]